# What will happen if the inducing charge is way greater than the charges on an induced body?

Tags: electrostatics, electromagnetic-induction, conductors

For induction in conductors, we know that $Q_{induced} = -Q_{inducing}$. But I don’t understand *why the magnitude of charge induced on a conductor by a charged body is equal to the charge on it*. What if the conductor on which the charge has to be induced has less charges (positives and negatives) than the net charges on a charged body?

> Illustration of my question-:
> We have two bodies, one uncharged having charges +A and -A $(Q_{net} = 0)$, and another charged body with +B charge. Now when the charged body is brought near the uncharged body, +B attracts -A charge and repels +A charge. Let’s suppose our uncharged conductor has a lesser number of charges than the net charge on the charged body. So how is $Q_{induced} = -Q_{inducing}$ valid since +B > -A.  
>  If the uncharged conductor doesn’t have -B charges but less than that so how is the +B charged body going to create a charge separation of +B & -B on the uncharged conductor??

(clarification - I’m not talking about ‘*charging* by induction’ but only charge-separation/induction.)

Edit: I’ve modified my question, after some studying. So, please address this doubt.

Thanks:)

Comment: How small do you imagine your rod if it contains only 20e it is made up of 20 atoms! So the law you mentioned does not apply

Comment: @Apogee point $Q_{induced}=-Q_{inducing}$ this is valid for macroscopic systems and in metals. Only thing that is valid in both cases is charge conservation.

Comment: It seems like you have found a limitation of the approximations assumed. You would have to further specify a more physical situation to find out what happens. In the end, I would wonder how you could get so much charge on the inducting body that it can't be compensated by the other body.

Comment: @Dr.Nate - I just have this hypothetical case in my mind. It would be a great help if you could elaborate on what situations are possible for the same.

Comment: Once your approximation breaks down, you have to go back to the beginning and change things to make it physical. I think one assumption that normally comes with this is: "a conductor is a limitless source of +ve and -ve charge pairs."  You want to break that assumption, so you need to replace it with a microscopic description of conductors. That means you need to get mathy.

Comment: @Dr.Nate With some math of it, will it be possible to explain the equations or workings behind them in simpler terms? I’m really keen to see how things are calculated for this!

Comment: Objects are made of atoms. Atoms are the source of negative and positive charge. Maybe an even better way of stating an assumption is "the induction of charges negligibly alters the conductor". You want to break this assumption.  You are asking to move all the charges around. I don't know what would exactly happen, but I guess that in a vacuum with nothing else but the inducing charge around, the conductor would probably fly apart. But, *you* need to specify the exact conditions when you remake your model after you break the assumption. Also, how could you get the inducing charge so large?

Comment: @Dr.Nate - I think instead of taking the inducing charge very large, we could also take the induced charge smaller compared to the inducing charge. So I understood that it would be right to say that  Qinduced = −Qinducing conditioned the induced conductor has enough charges that can compensate for the charges on the inducing body. And my hypothetical case is an extreme case where this would not apply. Am I correct? And thanks a lot sir for helping!